# TCL_LIB_SPEC missing in modules install

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to install `modules` from SourceForge and I'm getting an error that a variable named TCL_LIB_SPEC is not set.  What is this supposed to be set to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer here is to install the TCL development package

```
 % yum install tcl-devel
```

This gives you a `tclConfig.sh` file at `/usr/lib64/tcl8.5`

So

```
 % cd /usr/lib64/tcl8.5
 % . ./tclConfig.sh
```

Then `configure` works.

Comment: Did you mean `. tclConfig.sh` or `./tclConfig.sh`?

Comment: ".sh" is bash script. It can be run by "." or "sh" or "source" depending on the situation. In this case, use "sh ./tclConfig.sh"

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to be set to the instructions to use with your compiler for linking against the Tcl C library, and it should (conventionally) be generated by running the relevant `configure` script inside a Tcl source distribution. Or a distribution of Tcl (e.g., on Linux perhaps called `tcl-dev`) may have alternate correct values already set up.

Comment: I installed tcl using yum. But I don't see it if I open a new shell. Do I need to reboot?

Comment: I think it is "tclsh" not "tcl".

Comment: On Ubuntu it was `apt install tcl-dev`